iOS application .backgroundTask() not working even though there are no errors
I'm looking to update the app icon badge count for an iOS app while the app is not in use. The twist here is that the badge count does not depend upon external events and push notifications, as most of the examples I've found online do. Instead, the badge count should silently update based upon the relationship between the underlying SwiftData and the passage of time.
Here's an example based upon the default code when a user opens a new SwiftData and CloudKit Xcode project, just with the "Background Modes" capability added to "Signing & Capabilities", the "UpdateBadge" task added to "Info" as a "Permitted background task scheduler identifier", and a background task added to the app file. I've attempted to use the background task approach outlined in the 2022 WWDC "Efficiency awaits" talk.
This code does NOT throw any errors - it just doesn't update the icon badge number as intended when the app is not in use. Any idea what I need to do differently?
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData
import BackgroundTasks

@main
struct BadgeNumberExampleApp: App {
    
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var phase
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    var sharedModelContainer: ModelContainer = {
        let schema = Schema([
            Item.self,
        ])
        let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)

        do {
            return try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
        }
    }()
    
    

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(sharedModelContainer)
        .onChange(of: phase) {
            switch phase {
            case .background:
                scheduleAppRefresh()
            default: break
            }
        }
        .backgroundTask(.appRefresh("UpdateBadge")) {
            await scheduleAppRefresh()
            await updateIconBadge()
        } // End of .backgroundTask(.appRefresh("UpdateBadge"))
    }
    
    // MARK: - Methods
    
    func scheduleAppRefresh() {
        
        let refreshTime = Date().addingTimeInterval(5) // 5 seconds from now
        
        let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: "UpdateBadge")
        request.earliestBeginDate = refreshTime
        try? BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
        print("*** BadgeNumberExampleApp scheduleAppRefresh() just ran... ****")
    }
    
    func updateIconBadge() async {
        
        let now = Date()
        let pastWeek = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: now)
        
        // @Query var items: [Item]
        let context = sharedModelContainer.mainContext
        let query = FetchDescriptor<Item>(
            predicate: #Predicate { $0.timestamp >= pastWeek!})

        do {
            let items = try context.fetch(query)
            let badgeNumber = items.count
            try await UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setBadgeCount(badgeNumber)
            print("*** badge number = \(badgeNumber)")
        } catch {
            print("*** error updating badge number ***")
        }
        
    } // End of updateIconBadge()

}

// Needed in order to request user permission to show the badge
import Foundation
import UIKit

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: .badge) { completed, error in
            print(completed)
        }
        return true
    } // End of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
    
}

// Default ContentView code - nothing new here, just including it to show a fully reproducible example
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var items: [Item]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink {
                        Text("Item at \(item.timestamp, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .standard))")
                    } label: {
                        Text(item.timestamp, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .standard))
                    }
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(timestamp: Date())
            modelContext.insert(newItem)
        }
    }
}



See this - you can't use @Query outside of a view. You have to perform a fetch directly on the model context

Thank you for that reference, Paulw11! Very helpful. I've edited my code to use FetchDescriptor and it now compiles. It's not yet updating the badge number when the app is not in use, so I'm still missing something about BackgroundTasks, but I'm closer than before. Thank you!
